# Submenu hides when trying to interact with any of the buttons

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I' am using bootstrap 3 dropdown menu on my site. The code below works fine, the problem is that when i click or try to interact with any of the element inside **class="dropdown-menu"** the submenu hides.

**Example** if I click on any of the buttons inside **class="dropdown-menu"** the whole submenu items.

**Below is the code in place**

```
<li class="header-request dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle sr-only" id="request-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="request-dropdown">
    <div class="col-md-0 media-header bold">Friend Request</div>
    <div class="scroll">
    <?php
    $session_id = GET_SESSION_ID_VALUE(ENCRYPTION_KEY);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM requests WHERE request_to='$session_id' LIMIT 10";
    $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
    if($db->NUM_ROWS() > 0){
      $rows = $db->FETCH_OBJECT();
      foreach($rows as $row){
        $request_id = $row->request_id;
        $request_from = $row->request_from;
    ?>
    <div class="row pad0" id="header-request-ID-<?php echo $request_id; ?>">
      <div class="col-md-6 name"><a href="/<?php echo get_username_by_id($request_from); ?>"><?php echo get_name_by_ID($request_from); ?></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Confirm</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove-request" data-ajax="header-remove-request" data-id="<?php echo $profile_hash; ?>">Reject</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
      }
    }
    ?>
    </div>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: as your issue seems to not be linked to `mysql` or `php`, it could be interesting to have an example of what the `html` code of your dropdown looks like.

Comment: could u plz provide http://www.bootply.com or http://jsfiddle.net/  for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it....

Working here- http://www.bootply.com/117795

```
$('.dropdown-menu input,.dropdown-menu button').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, was able to solve it with JavaScript. This is the working code on my site:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(){
    return false;
});
```